# Implementing twitter gem in rails 5 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm having issues trying to experiment with the twitter gem. My rails app is pretty simple. No devise or authentication at the moment. I'm more interesting in just making API calls and collect batch data to experiment with D3 at a later point.

I'm trying to follow the vague documentation and this is as far as I got.

```
# config/initializers/twitter_client.rb    
require 'twitter'

twitter = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key =         ENV['##############']
  config.consumer_secret =      ENV['##############']
  config.access_token =         ENV['##############']
  config.access_token_secret =  ENV['##############']
end
```

So now I want to `byebug` during an action in order to poke around. However, the controller doesn't seem to understand the `twitter` variable. I've tried making them instance and global. I am probably failing to `require` something. But, I was under the impression initializer files are accessable everywhere by default.

Answer (score 1):

If you want global variable. Use **::** operator

```
# config/initializers/twitter_client.rb    
require 'twitter'

::MyTwitter = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key =         ENV['##############']
  config.consumer_secret =      ENV['##############']
  config.access_token =         ENV['##############']
  config.access_token_secret =  ENV['##############']
end
```

Then you will be able to use **MyTwitter** anywhere in your app.

Comment: I'd rather not make it global if that's possible. I tried just throwing it into a `Twitter` class

However, it didn't like that and threw out `Twitter is not a class (TypeError)` error when I booted up the server.